# arm v8 load store exclusive instructions (ldaxr stxr) dependencies

Tags: arm

I am trying to use load/store exclusive instructions in my standalone code but it is giving me error when it is beeing execute. can someone tell me the dependency of the load/store exclusive instructions in armv8? in armv7 we need to enable SMP bit which inturn enables MMU and enables the exclusive instructions.

i have enabled the MMU and D/i caches in armv8. can you please tell me how to set the shared bit for pages in page table?

Comment: “it is giving me error when it is beeing execute”: what errors?

Comment: synchronous abort exception